# Accessing specific element of an array

Tags: python

I'm unsure of how to access an element in an array (of arrays?). Basically, I need to be able to assign random numbers to a series of arrays but I'm not sure how indexing works.

```
array_20 = np.zeros((5,10))
a = [[array_20]]*10
#This gives me 10 arrays of 5x10. I'd like to be able to then assign random
#numbers to all of the elements.
```

Comment: Just a 3 layer for loop, then you can access every element in `a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`numpy.random.rand`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html) like so:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(10, 5, 10)
```

You can then index `a` like a python list. (i.e. `a[1][2][0]`)

Comment: But then how do you access a particular array within a? How is it indexed?

Comment: Just edited but it's exactly like a normal python list